# How to check scroll position in front of div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I created one parent div that has scroll. It has children divs which have text content, I want to check if scroll is in front of one of the child divs.

I tried it by comparing top scroll position with

**div.offset().top**

but as I am scrolling down div will calculate only visible height from parent with offset top position and scroll will calculate it's top from starting of parent. I am checking scroll's position like so:

```
if(scrollPosition>div.offset().top && scrollPostion (div.offset.top+div.height) ) {//scroll present }
```

What is correct way of getting div's top position?

Blockquote

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to use `scrollTop` of parent and compare that with `position().top` (not `offset`) of child divs - position is relative to the parent, whereas offset is relative to the document

Comment: Actually, i am using offset of child div relative to document and scrolltop of scroll...as i will scroll child div..child div will go up...as child divs have different heights..so it would be hard to get exact offset of child div which can be compared to scrolltop of scroll

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the offsetTop of the parents elements.

```
var t = div.offsetTop;
var p = div;
while (p=p.offsetParent)
    t += p.offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose that two boxes and one has scroll named `container` and another is child named `target`:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="target"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var container = document.getElementById('container'),
        target = document.getElementById('target');
    if((container.scrollTop - target.offsetTop) > 0 && (container.scrollTop - target.offsetTop) < target.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('in range');
    }
</script>
```

`target.offsetHeight` is not contains margin.

Comment: It's correct to get scroll for one child..but if that child goes out of document and try to find offset of following child which is in document...offset of this child would be from document but scroll top would be from first child so this calculation won't be correct in that case.